# How can I copy files from folders and subfolders to another folder in R?

Tags: r, file, file-manipulation

I would like to copy **files only** from 1 root folder that has 100's of folders and subfolders. I do not want to copy the folders. I just want to copy all the files (*.iso, *.txt, *.docx, *.pdf etc.) there are in these folders to another folder.

My code:

```
setwd("/Users/RLearner/Desktop/RDMS")

if (file.exists(list.files(path=".",recursive=TRUE)))
  file.copy(from=".", to="/Users/RLearner/Desktop/Test", recursive=TRUE)
```

But this code is copying the root folder as it is into my desired `Test` folder. I just want to copy the files that these folders have?

Comment: Does `?file.rename` help?

Comment: No, I thought it was for renaming files and folders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do:

```
from.dir <- "/Users/RLearner/Desktop/RDMS"
to.dir   <- "/Users/RLearner/Desktop/Test"
files    <- list.files(path = from.dir, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
for (f in files) file.copy(from = f, to = to.dir)
```

Comment: It didn't work for me:( Can you please explain this? Thanks EDIT: IT WORKED!!!! The error was from my side. What a genius you are!! Thank you. Have a great weekend. @flodel

Comment: To copy files in nested folders I used file.copy(list.files(from.dir, full.names = TRUE), to.dir, recursive=TRUE).